# Find whether user has subscribed youtube channel using Youtube data api

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am developing an application in which user can subscribe to various channels in my app itself. So to save api request i want to know whether user has already subscribed a youtube channel or not.  While researching I have found some code and modified that to my requirements:

```
static public boolean checkIfUserAlreadySubscribed(String channelyoutubeid) {
    SubscriptionListResponse response = null;
    try {
        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails");
        parameters.put("forChannelId", channelyoutubeid);
        parameters.put("mine", "true");

        YouTube.Subscriptions.List subscriptionsListForChannelIdRequest = MainActivity
                .mService.subscriptions().list(parameters.get("part").toString());
        if (parameters.containsKey("forChannelId") && parameters.get("forChannelId") != "") {
            subscriptionsListForChannelIdRequest.setForChannelId(parameters
                    .get("forChannelId").toString());
        }

        if (parameters.containsKey("mine") && parameters.get("mine") != "") {
            boolean mine = (parameters.get("mine") == "true") ? true : false;
            subscriptionsListForChannelIdRequest.setMine(mine);
        }

        response = subscriptionsListForChannelIdRequest.execute();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (response != null) {
        //What should i do here
    } else {
        //whta should i pass
    }
}
```

On executing my code response value is always not null whether user has subscribed or not .Can anyone suggest me what to do??

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve channels which a user has already subscribed, you may want to try using [`Activities: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) with `mine` parameter set to `true`. A successful request will return response body with activity resource:

```
"contentDetails": {
    "subscription": {
      "resourceId": {
        "kind": string,
        "channelId": string,
      }
    }
}
```

`contentDetails.subscription.resourceId.channelId` is the ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the channel that the user subscribed to.